# maven and jdk8 on Alpine Linux image

Tags: linux, maven, java-8

This is my first time working with an Alpine linux image. Its part of a Jenkins build pipeline.

When I try to compile my maven build (which requires Java 1.8) ... it gives an error suggested there is no compiler installed.

However, I confirmed its installed ... multiple ways;

1. Echo the JAVA_HOME variable which returns
   `/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8-openjdk`
2. Tested to confirm the compiler is there;
   by running "${JAVA_HOME}/javac -version" ... which returns;

```
/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8-openjdk/bin/javac -version
javac 1.8.0_222
```

3. However, maven still points to the JRE ...

```
Apache Maven 3.5.2 (138edd61fd100ec658bfa2d307c43b76940a5d7d; 2017-10-18T07:58:13Z)
Maven home: /usr/share/java/maven-3
Java version: 1.8.0_222, vendor: IcedTea
Java home: /usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8-openjdk/jre
Default locale: en_US, platform encoding: UTF-8
OS name: "linux", version: "4.19.84-coreos", arch: "amd64", family: "unix"
```

I tried manually installed the JDK ... but doesn't seem to help;

```
            apk update
            apk add openjdk8
            apk add maven
```

Any suggestions? I need Java 8 to compile this app ... and currently every attempt to do a "mvn clean install" results in a failure, as below;

```
[ERROR] COMPILATION ERROR : 
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] No compiler is provided in this environment. Perhaps you are running on a JRE rather than a JDK?
```

Comment: seems to say that there isn't a compiler available. I don't usually add manually. What you do there to add maven works for me. Try running javac -version in a sample build. Also check environment variables.

Answer (score 0):

Tried many different ideas and then eventually thought about setting the path to the compiler and amazingly, now it works!

```
            export PATH=${PATH}:${JAVA_HOME}/bin
            mvn clean install
```